# PySpark: finding the time difference between the two timestamp of list of timestamps in a PySpark dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark Dataframe and having a column named `timestamp` which contains an array of arrays of timestamps in it and not of fixed length such as:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|timestamp                                                                                                                           |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[[2022-01-01 12:00:00, 2022-01-02 15:30:00]]                                                                                        |
|[[2022-01-01 12:00:00, 2022-01-02 14:30:00], [2022-01-02 12:00:00, 2022-01-03 19:30:00], [2022-01-02 12:00:00, 2022-01-03 15:30:00]]|
|[[2022-01-01 12:00:00, 2022-01-02 16:30:00], [2022-01-03 12:00:00, 2022-01-04 17:30:00]]                                            |
|[]                                                                                                                                  |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I am trying to get the time difference of each array containing the timestamp in seconds.

So The output would be:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+
|timestamp                                                                                                                           |    time_diff                 |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+
|[[2022-01-01 12:00:00, 2022-01-02 15:30:00]]                                                                                        |[99000.0]                     |
|[[2022-01-01 12:00:00, 2022-01-02 14:30:00], [2022-01-02 12:00:00, 2022-01-03 19:30:00], [2022-01-02 12:00:00, 2022-01-03 15:30:00]]|[95400.0,199800.0,185400.0]   |
|[[2022-01-01 12:00:00, 2022-01-02 16:30:00], [2022-01-03 12:00:00, 2022-01-04 17:30:00]]                                            |[189000.0,192600.0]           |
|[]                                                                                                                                  |[]
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+
```

Hence the each value in a a list contains the difference of time.

In Short i want to do this:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+
|timestamp                                                                                                                           |    time_diff                 |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+
|[[t1,t2]]                                                                                                                           |[(t2-t1)]                     |
|[[t3,t4], [t5,t6], [t7,t8]]                                                                                                         |[(t4-t3),(t6-t5),(t8-t7)]     |
|[[t9,t10], [t11,t12]]                                                                                                               |[(t10-t9),(t12-t11)]          |
|[]                                                                                                                                  |[]                            |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+
```

Here t1,t2....tn is the timestamp in the arrays

NOTE: I am using spark 3.x

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `transform` to map each element of the outer array to the time difference of the inner arrays as follows:

```py
result = df.withColumn("time_diff",
    F.transform(F.col("timestamp"), lambda x: (x.getItem(1) - x.getItem(0)).cast("long")))
```

Comment: Hi @Oli Thanks for the response,
but I am only getting the first array time diff, is I am missing something. can you please explain.

Comment: Have you pasted everything? If the schema is what you described. Transform should transform each element. Can you provide the output of `printSchema` please?

Comment: I realized that the name of column I had used was not correct. I changed it. Have you found a solution?